# Host IP Address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 on Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, network-programming, ip

I am trying to get the user Host, IP, and Port using:

```
request.getRemoteHost()
request.getRemoteAddr()
request.getRemotePort()
```

But I am getting:

**Host:** 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
**IP:** Address null
**Port:** 51111

How do I get the correct IP address, noting that our network IP start with 10.100.x.x

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the `localhost` in your request URI, then the IPv6 is `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. Instead of using `localhost`, use your IPv4 in your request URI to get the *correct* IP.

Comment: thanks that was the problem, i was testing from a localhost, But i got the same IP for both request.getRemoteHost()
request.getRemoteAddr(), so how do i get the Netbios name of the Computer?

Comment: Ok i got it through: InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteHost());
    String computerName = inetAddress.getHostName();
    if (computerName.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost")) {
     computerName = InetAddress.getLocalHost()
       .getCanonicalHostName();
    }